Spring Shell Enumerations:: Displaying all values in Spring-Shell-Documentation
I have a Spring Shell Option that use an Enumeration.
public enum FilesType {files, dirs, all}

In the Help documentation only the type is displayed.
ie:
shell:>help mycommand 

       -t MyCommands.FilesType
       Files or directories or both (all)
       [Optional, default = all]

       --help or -h 
       help for find
       [Optional]

Question is, how can I list the values under the help documentation, as the MyCommands.FilesType (enum type) is quite useless when it comes to documentation. The values would be more useful and appropriate.
Any help is much appreciated.
